# Executing just multiple python lines in VIM

Tags: vim

My code is:

```
stuff = 'bla'
print(stuff)
```

I'm using the vim editor on linux mint to learn it.

So my question is:

I also have other code snippets above. But I want to for example try this two codes of lines out in the vim editor. Is there a way that i can execute that? Like in vscode where i can "Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal) with Shift + Enter.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It helps if you structure your question better. 
1. Ask the main question you have
2. Show an example of what you want on a new line
3. Other stuff

Comment: I edited the question for better understanding.

Comment: You won't learn Vim by asking random questions on random internet forums. You will learn Vim by following the built-in user manual, `:help user-manual`, which is a very easy to follow tutorial.

Comment: @romainl Thanks, i'll work on that mindset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim also sports a `:terminal` command. Looking at [`:help :terminal`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#%3Aterminal) will reveal the following information:

```
:[range]ter[minal] [options] [command]
            Open a new terminal window.

            If [command] is provided run it as a job and connect
            the input and output to the terminal.

            [...]

            If [range] is given the specified lines are used as
            input for the job.  It will not be possible to type
            keys in the terminal window.
```

This looks pretty complete: you can run a command (here: your Python interpreter) in a terminal, feeding it some lines from your buffer as input.

You would enter linewise Visual mode with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, select the lines to run and call

```
:'<,'>terminal python
```

where `'<,'>` stands for the current visual selection. Vim will already populate your command line with this when you type `:` in Visual mode.

On hitting enter, Vim will open a terminal window which will show the output (if any) of the Python code you just ran. Type `:q` to close the terminal and return to your normal editing.

For convenience, consider writing a command or a mapping to quickly run Python code. The following line will define a `:Python` command that runs the current visual selection or the whole buffer if nothing is selected:

```
:command -range=% Python <line1>,<line2>terminal python
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to be clear: VIM can not execute python code. You need a python interpreter for this. For example, an IPython shell.

Second, to execute python code written in the VIM text editor you can use IPython and a vim plugin, [vim-ipython-cell](https://github.com/hanschen/vim-ipython-cell).

This plugin allows Jupyter Notebook style cell execution using a custom defined ipython shell. I have been working with this since a while and I can recommend.

It builds on a more basic vim plugin [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime), which technically can also do what you want.

Another option, which I haven't tried, is [nvim-ipy](https://github.com/bfredl/nvim-ipy).